# Use Torify for Android Studio: Operation not permitted

Tags: 16.04, android, tor, android-studio

I'm trying to cross Android Studio from Tor By using torify.

I run Android Studio by:

```
sudo torify ./studio.sh
```

after launch Android Studio this message occurred:

> Operation not permitted (Socket creation failed)

Terminal Log:

```
[Mar 03 10:14:58] WARNING torsocks[21709]: [syscall] Unsupported syscall number 229. Denying the call (in tsocks_syscall() at syscall.c:465)
^C[Mar 03 10:15:00] ERROR torsocks[21709]: Unable to resolve. Status reply: 4 (in socks5_recv_resolve_reply() at socks5.c:666)
[Mar 03 10:15:00] ERROR torsocks[21709]: Unable to resolve. Status reply: 4 (in socks5_recv_resolve_reply() at socks5.c:666)
Failed to retrieve the list of available network interfaces
java.net.SocketException: Operation not permitted (Socket creation failed)
```

torsocks shows same message too.

I use Ubuntu 16.04 if it helps.

Anyone can help me to fix it?

Comment: Are you also typing Sudo whit a capitalized letter? it should be sudo whit no capitalized letters. or are this just a typo in the question?

Comment: Also, you have to try to resolve this issue Failed to retrieve the list of available network interfaces